# wp_list_categories() - current-cat class also inside posts?

Tags: custom-post-types, custom-taxonomy, url-rewriting, categories

I wrote my own function to list all taxonomy terms of a certain taxonomy …

```
function wr_list_taxonomy($taxonomy, $orderby, $hierarchical) {
    $show_count   = 0;
    $pad_counts   = 0;
    $title        = '';

    $args = array(
      'taxonomy'     => $taxonomy,
      'orderby'      => $orderby,
      'show_count'   => $show_count,
      'pad_counts'   => $pad_counts,
      'hierarchical' => $hierarchical,
      'title_li'     => $title
    );

    return wp_list_categories( $args );
}
```

So this function works exactly like `wp_list_categories()` and also puts out a "current-cat" class once I'm on a term-page.

So imagine my URL structure …

```
www.mysite.com/term //current-cat works perfect
www.mysite.com/term/a-post-associated-with-this-term //current-cat not assigned
```

Is there a chance to also make the "current-cat" class work once I'm in a post but within this "category" just like pointed out above?

**update:**

The `wr_list_taxonomy()` function is called inside my `header.php` file.

```
<nav id="main-nav">
            <ul class="wr-nav" role="navigation">
                    <?php
                        global $post;
                        $taxonomy = 'event_type';
                        $term_id = 0;
                        $terms = wp_get_post_terms( $post->ID, $taxonomy, array("fields" => "ids") );
                        if ( !empty($terms) )
                            $term_id = $terms[0];
                        wr_list_taxonomy($taxonomy, 'name', 1, $term_id); ?>
            </ul>
</nav>
```

I updated the `wr_list_taxonomy()` function to your version.

Moreover I have another function that might be relevant for the thing I want …

```
/**
 * Add category-slug as classname to wp_list_categories()
 */

add_filter('wp_list_categories', 'add_slug_css_list_categories', 10, 2);

function add_slug_css_list_categories($list, $args) {

    if ( $args["taxonomy"] == "event_type" ) {
        $cats = get_terms('event_type');
        $class = 'term term-';
    } else {
        $cats = get_categories();
        $class = 'category-';
    }

    foreach( $cats as $cat ) {
        $find = 'cat-item-' . $cat->term_id . '"';
        $replace = $class . $cat->slug . '"';
        $list = str_replace( $find, $replace, $list );
        $find = 'cat-item-' . $cat->term_id . ' ';
        $replace = $class . $cat->slug . ' ';
        $list = str_replace( $find, $replace, $list );
    }

    return $list;
}
```

This function adds the "category-slug" to each `<li>` item in the `wr_list_taxonomy()` function. This works fine.

I just need to have the "current-cat" class also applied when I'm on a single.php (post) site that is associated with the "current category" i'm in.

Comment: Does `$terms` returns any term id? Just checking, you did update the `wr_list_taxonomy(`) function according to my code right?

Comment: Yes it does! `$term_id` holds the ID of the term - also inside a post. So that seems to work, but the class is not applied

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes off course. You just need to get the term id and put it on the args. Check [`wp_list_categories()`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Template_Tags/wp_list_categories#Parameters)

```
function wr_list_taxonomy($taxonomy, $orderby, $hierarchical, $cat_id) {
    $show_count   = 0;
    $pad_counts   = 0;
    $title        = '';
    $cat_id = 0;

    $args = array(
      'taxonomy'     => $taxonomy,
      'orderby'      => $orderby,
      'show_count'   => $show_count,
      'pad_counts'   => $pad_counts,
      'hierarchical' => $hierarchical,
      'title_li'     => $title,
      'current_category' => $cat_id
    );

    return wp_list_categories( $args );
}
```

You have to pass the category id or term id. To make it work.

**How Do You Get Category ID?**

For Example:

```
    global $post;
    $taxonomy = 'my-tax';
    $term_id = 0;
    if(is_singular('post')){ // post type is optional.
      $terms = wp_get_post_terms( $post->ID, $taxonomy, array("fields" => "ids") );
      if(!empty($terms))
        $term_id = $terms[0]; //we need only one term id
    }

   wr_list_taxonomy($taxonomy, $orderby, $hierarchical, $term_id);
```

Its just a simple example and there are other ways to do it. It depends on where you are using the code.

Comment: Thank you, but this doesn't make a difference. The "navigation" that lists my taxonomy-terms doesn't have "current-cat" applied once i'm inside a post. On the term-page itself the "current-cat" class is assigned to the `<li>`s. I updated my question with a few more details.

Comment: Well, weird! now it does work after I changed the variable `$cat_id` inside of the `wr_list_taxonomy()` to `term_id` as well. `'current_category' => $term_id`

Comment: One last problem though … `Trying to get property of non-object in /Users/my/htdocs/wr/wp-content/themes/wr/header.php on line 91` this happens if no post is assigned to a term on a term-page.

Comment: use a if statement with `is_singular()` conditional. Updated my answer.

Comment: thank you! And the last question … is there a way to make this get term id more "functional" … I don't want all this php in my header.php. Is it possible to write a function `get_term_id()` that does all that?

Comment: actually you can add those code to your custom function `wr_list_taxonomy()` so, the function will do more and less code on `header.php`

Answer (score 0):

Based on the accepted answer, You just need to pass an extra parameter in. I just write down complete code so it's easy for understanding.

```
    <?php  $taxonomy = 'category';
 
 $term_id = 0;
    if(is_singular('post')){ // post type is optional.
      $terms = wp_get_post_terms( $post->ID, $taxonomy, array("fields" => "ids") );
      if(!empty($terms))
        $term_id = $terms[0]; //we need only one term id
    }

 echo wp_list_categories(
   array(
     'show_count'   => false,
   'pad_counts'   => false,
   'use_desc_for_title' => false,
   'title_li'=>'',
   'hierarchical' =>false,
   'current_category' => $term_id
   )
 );
 ?>
```